# How can I connect my Sony Xperia C4 E5333 to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, usb-debugging

I want to connect my Sony Xperia C4 E5333 to Android Studio for debugging my app, but Android Studio does not show my phone in ADB window.

I tried to install the USB driver for my phone but I can not find an USB driver for the E5333 model. In ADB, I have the Google USB driver installed. I installed Sony PC Companion 2.1, but when it tried updating, I got an error.

How can I connect my phone to Android Studio?

Comment: What error did *Sony PC Companion* show?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Sony driver for your phone, not Google USB Driver.

This one should do it: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-c4-driver/

Also, you need to get to developer options and enable USB debugging. After that you are good to go.

Comment: In your link write - Phone driver for Xperia C (C2305, S39h) (Microsoft Windows™ XP 32bit/64bit and later). Use drivers for debugging, or when erased from phone. I writ - MY PHONE E5333

Answer (score 0):

- Get the latest `Google Usb Driver` from `SDK MANAGER > EXTRA`
- Open `Device manager`.
- in `Other Devices` find your phone with a ? mark beside it
- Right click on it and choose Update Driver. You would see this screen,
  [image]
- Choose `Browse My Computer For Driver Software`. You would see this screen,
  [image]
- Choose Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer. You would see this screen,
  [image]
- Choose `Android Device` and click Next. You would see this screen,
  [image]
- Choose `Android Adb Interface` and then click on `Have Disk`. You would see this screen,
  [image]
- Browse to where you installed your Sdk, SDK_PATH > extras > google > usb_driver
- Click ok then next and your device installed !
- if you still don't see your device type these commands in your cmd

  adb kill-server

  adb start-server

Comment: >Browse to where you installed your Sdk, SDK_PATH > extras > google > usb_driver
not found driver in derictory

Comment: did you get latest usb driver from sdk manager ? @user5620472